# Unable to import module Error in AWS Lambda Nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, amazon-textract

I am working on an AWS Lambda where I need to use AWS `Textract`, for this, I have used `AWS-SDK`, with `AWS-SDK` I was able to import `s3`, but AWS Textract is not working, when I deploy and test it shows,

`Unable to import module 'src/functions/routes/handler': Error`

I think it has something to do with packaging, like may be It is not packaging the relevant file, but not sure and I don't know how to make it package if it is the problem, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your question will not be answered if you do not provide the code for people to review and respond to. Include the code body directly in your question, or add a link to a runnable repo if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any code to go on, I will consider the possibility that you have properly written your import code and this error is a valid response to an issue. In that case, you should note that there are issues with importing Textract in Lambda via the aws-sdk. See this reported issue:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2728

For a thorough and thoughtful example of using Textract with a Lambda service, consider this excellent article posted with complete details:

https://medium.com/@sumindaniro/aws-textract-with-lambda-walkthrough-ed4473aedd9d